# Simulate URL entering on java

Tags: java

So I have a problem where if I type this link on the browser and hit enter, an activation happens. I just want to do the same through Java. I don't need any kind of response from the URL. It should just do the same as entering the URL on a browser. Currently my code doesn't throw an error, but I don't think its working because the activation is not happening. My code:

```
        public static void enableMachine(String dns){
     try {
            String req= "http://"+dns+"/username?username=sputtasw";
            URL url = new URL(req);
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();
            /*BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
            String strTemp = "";
            while (null != (strTemp = br.readLine())) {
                System.out.println(strTemp);
            }*/
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

What's the problem?

Comment: maybe your link triggers some redirection, so it's better to try a headless browser such as http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/

Comment: What do you mean by "an activation happens"? What exactly do you mean? Does anything happen in the browser? Or on the server that is behind the URL?

Comment: Yeah, when i hit the url on browser and hit enter, it sends a signal to a remote server and i get a page displaying that activation is successful.

Comment: @Leo I dont want to try in a browser. I just have to pass the code to activate something by entering this url like i did with my browser

Comment: are you sure there are no javascript, cookies or redirection involved?

Comment: if there isn't, try using wget or curl first to be sure.

Comment: I dont know. that web page is not mine. I am just passing the URL. I just want to do by code what i do by browser. Like typing www.google.com and hitting enter on browser

Comment: Read the full response from the connection and see what the server is responding or whether there's something entirely different going on. As far as I know just using ``connect()`` is not enough to actually send the GET request.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do that with an URLConnection, it isn't sufficient to just open the connection with connect, you also have to send e.g. an HTTP request etc.

That said, i think it would be easier, if you use an HTTP client like the one from Apache HttpComponents (http://hc.apache.org/). Just do a GET request with the HTTP client, this would be the same as visiting the page with a browser (those clients usually also supports redirection etc.).

Answer (score 0):

You may use `HttpUrlConnectionClass` to do the job:

```
URL url = new URL("http://my.url.com");
HttpURLConnection httpCon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
httpCon.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
httpCon.setDoOutput(true);
httpCon.setRequestMethod("POST");

String params = "foo=42&bar=buzz";

DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(httpCon.getOutputStream());
wr.writeBytes(params);
wr.flush();
wr.close();

httpCon.connect();

int responseCode = httpCon.getResponseCode();
```

You may as well use "GET" request method and just append parameters to the url.